# Can MATCH function in an array formula to return multiple matches?

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas, excel-match

I tried to use the `MATCH` function in an array formula to return multiple matches (by default it only returns the first match). However, this doesn't seem to work. How can I solve this problem without a complex, unreadable formula?

Comment: It is quite necessary, I've done this before and gotten multiple comments because people didn't like me answering my own question. Just because SO has rules doesn't mean people know about them.

Comment: Could you give a small example with expected result to illustrate your query?

Comment: Can you insert the answer as part of the question and say something like "this is what i'm currently using"? This would then have potential for interesting discussion in answers rather than comments. For example your current code only allows for range arguments but could be made more flexible and compact. The code in fact might not even be required as there is native functionality which does this.

Comment: @pnuts thanks for the link. imho the code is redundant anyway as there is a native method available: `application.match` can output an array of values with ranges or arrays as input arguments.

Comment: @puts,  indeed hence why responses have not been conclusive so far. But the question is likely to attract search hits and the current answer appears somewhat misleading to readers so it might be better to indicate otherwise in case of no further clarification.

Answer (score 4):

How about this, without VBA? [entered on cell C9 as an array formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, where your searched column is A9:A24, and your search terms are in B1:B4], and dragged down to find multiple hits?

```
=SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH($B$1:$B$4,$A$9:$A$24,0),""),ROW()-ROW($C$8))
```

This first uses the array formula to show each 'hit' for any of the search terms matched in the searched column, and then using the Small function with reference to the current cell's row, it returns the earliest hit, then the 2nd hit, then the 3rd hit, etc.

Beyond this point, the reference points to the searched array can be used as needed (converted to the row location of an index function, etc.).

**EDIT**
On further review of the results from this formula, it only returns a single hit for each search term, even if that search term appears multiple times. To resolve this, I first used the formula:

```
=SMALL(IF($A$9:$A$24=$B$1,ROW($A$9:$A$24),""),ROW()-ROW($E$8))
```

This shows each hit for a match of the search term found in B1. Here is where I am stuck. I could only figure out how to resolve with the admittedly manual:

```
=SMALL(IF($A$9:$A$24={"a","b","c"},ROW($A$9:$A$24),""),ROW()-ROW($E$8))
```

Any suggestions on how to improve to allow multiple hits for multiple terms?

**EDIT - Additional option**

Okay, I've determined another method of picking up multiple hits. This one relies on considering the location of the previous matches already made. Depending on what you want your result vector to look like (which was never specified by the OP), the results from this are clean but the formula is fairly messy.

The first cell looks like this, in cell H9:
    =ADDRESS(MIN(IFERROR(MATCH($B$1:$B$4,$A$9:$A$24,0),""))+ROW($A$8),1)

This shows the address of the first cell which matches any of the search terms, using the formula noted further above.

The cell below that (and every cell after that), has this (also an array formula):

```
=ADDRESS(MIN(IFERROR(MATCH($B$1:$B$4,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(H9))+1,1)):$A$25,0),""))+ROW(INDIRECT(H9)),1)
```

This picks up the address of the cell found in the row above (adding 1 row to avoid re-hitting the same term), and from that new search column from that point to the end point (adding 1 row so that it properly stops at the last ending hit), it re-searches for any of the terms.

This one is again, not that clean [Yes I know there are some improvements I could make to determining what the search should be - either using the text manipulation functions or even doing a relative name reference that changes as you move down the column], but it is automated and, I would argue, cleaner than a VBA module. Especially as, depending on what you want your result vector to be, this could be much simpler.

Comment: (Slightly) different functionality that yours, but in terms of readability, I'd say this is cleaner than 50 lines of code.

Comment: Ah, on further testing this does not actually show multiple hits of the same search term - it only shows the first hit of each search term, in no particular order. Here's something which shows multiple hits for the same term, under the same method: =SMALL(IF($A$9:$A$24=$B$1,ROW($A$9:$A$24),""),ROW()-ROW($E$8)) ; I'm working on combining both features.

Answer (score 2):

Working\developing on the formulas posted by @Grade'Eh'Bacon ended up with this formula to retrieve all the results of a match function with several matches for several items.

Assuming input range is `B2:B17` and the range with the items to match is `F3:F5` enter this `FormulaArray` in `H3`

```
=IFERROR( SMALL( IF( $B$3:$B$17 = TRANSPOSE( $F$3:$F$5 ),
 1 + ROW( $B$3:$B$17 ) - ROW( $B$3 ), "" ), ROWS($2:2  ) ), "" )
```

[image]

*It's an `FormulaArray` returning all matches for several items*

All merits go to @Grade'Eh'Bacon for his great work on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure this out myself because I could not find an online resource that provided it, but yes: MATCH can return an array of multiple matches by doing this:

```
=MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT([Values_To_Match_Separated_By_Commas],,",",TRUE,1)),[Range_To_Lookup],0)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible with the built-in MATCH, however, using a VBA macro, you can achieve this:

```
Public Function MATCH_RANGE(values As Variant, ary As Variant, match_type As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim elementCount As Integer
    Dim result()
    Dim value As Variant

    Dim arySize As Integer
    arySize = UBound(ary.Value2, 1)

    Dim valueSize As Integer
    valueSize = UBound(values.Value2, 1)

    ReDim result(0 To arySize, 0 To 1)

    elementCount = 0

    For i = 1 To arySize
        For j = 1 To valueSize
            value = values(j, 1)
            If (match_type = -1 And ary(i, 1) <= value) Or (match_type = 0 And ary(i, 1) = value) Or (match_type = 1 And ary(i, 1) >= value) Then
                result(elementCount, 0) = i
                elementCount = elementCount + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = elementCount To arySize
        result(i, 0) = -100000000
    Next i

    MATCH_RANGE = result
End Function
```

This function both returns multiple matches and allows you to pass a range of multiple values that you want matched. I've found this useful a number of times. Feedback welcome to help improve this.

NOTE: You must spread this formula across a few cells using an array-formula (CRTL-SHIFT-ENTER), in order to see the multiple matches.

Comment: I'm not sure it's appropriate to post your own answer before even clarifying the question and allowing others the chance to answer!

Comment: @pnuts Ok, thanks. And MgSam: apologies. Nevertheless, it still seems strange to me, especially given the opening line of that answer "It is not possible..." and the lack of clarification. So a post can remain just thus? Self-answered and without response to comments to that post?

Comment: @pnuts Perhaps, though given that "complex" is a subjective term here, it would be better if the OP could give an example of a formula which they consider to have just crossed the boundary between "non-complex" and "complex". (They might also like to do likewise re the boundary between "readable" and "unreadable", for that matter.)

Comment: Would you please explain how this is supposed to be used. I'm trying to get the match of two items within a range: `=MATCH_RANGE( B8:B10 , B7:B21 , 0 )` it returns `#VALUE!`