# Combining rows with similar value in cell A1

Tags: excel, vba

I have two text columns in Excel with about 100k rows. I need to combine the text in column B where column A is similar. So from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Please show us what code you've tried.

Comment: I tried a formula that searches the column then updates. The problem is that there are too many rows and some of the data in column A could be as few as 2 or many as 27. I'm not for if a formula is the way to go.

Comment: If you want all the data to go into column B, I'm pretty sure you'll need VBA. If you can have the different matches ("apple", "tree", "water") in columns B, C, and D (etc.) then there's probably a formula to do so. You could also put them in C, D, E, etc. and then concatenate into B.  What formula have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are desperate for a formula solution see the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112330/5090027 In short - no easy way to do it, but with helper columns can be done.

Comment: What rule are you using to omit the `TREE` in B1 in your `From` table from B1 in your `To` table.  If you are combining all the words, shouldn't `B1` be `APPLE TREE TREE WATER`?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it works.

```
Sub CellStringCombine()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim intNumRange As Long
Dim strNewName As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim intRowDiff As Long
Dim intRow As Long

intNumRange = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

x = 1

'start looping through rows
Do While Cells(x, "A") <> ""
'set the placeholder variable, offset to the next row
    y = x + 1
'if the current row is equal to the next one, find out how far it's equal
    Do While Cells(x, "A") = Cells(y, "A")
        y = y + 1
    Loop
    intRowDiff = y - x

'check to see if the next row isn't equal. go to next row if yes.

    If intRowDiff = 1 Then
        GoTo NextCell
    End If

'Loop through the range identified
    For intRow = x To x + intRowDiff - 1

'If it's the first round, only take the name
        If intRow = x Then
            strNewName = Cells(intRow, "B")
'If it's after the first round, have it equal itself and put a space
        ElseIf intRow > x Then
            strNewName = strNewName + " " + Cells(intRow, "B")
        End If
    Next intRow

'Delete the identified range except the first row
    Range("A" & x + 1, "B" & y - 1).EntireRow.Delete

'Overwrite the text in column B
    Cells(x, "B") = strNewName

NextCell:
x = x + 1

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because I want to see if I could do it using an array.

```
Sub JSA()
Dim i&, t&
Dim StrArr() As String
Dim ows As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet

ReDim StrArr(0)

Set ows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set tws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

With ows
    For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        If i = 1 Then
            StrArr(0) = .Cells(i, 1) & "|"
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 1) <> .Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            ReDim Preserve StrArr(UBound(StrArr) + 1) As String
            StrArr(UBound(StrArr)) = .Cells(i, 1) & "|"
        End If
        StrArr(UBound(StrArr)) = StrArr(UBound(StrArr)) & .Cells(i, 2) & " "
    Next i
End With

For t = 1 To UBound(StrArr) + 1
    tws.Cells(t, 1) = Split(StrArr(t - 1), "|")(0)
    tws.Cells(t, 2) = Trim(Split(StrArr(t - 1), "|")(1))
Next t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time project I would copy columns A and B to a separte table, sort it by column A.

```
In column C (Row2) a formula "IIf(A2=A1;0;1)"
In column D (Row2) a formula "IIf(C1=1;B2;B1 & " " & B2)"
```

Then fill this until the last row. Copy the whole thing (Values only) into a different table and sort again (by C(downards) and A(upwards).