# Concatenate range in Excel with formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to concatenate an unbounded range of cells containing text with formulas. I have done some research and it looks like it is not possible but, I was thinking that maybe using circular reference it would be possible and I have not seen anyone tried before or commenting about it, and I tried myself but did not work.

The idea is the following. I have this data:

[image]

I want to not have into account the number of rows I have so let's call it x rows. X rows should change dinamically by adding a new letter and a new number

Then I want the list of letters whose values, for example, are less than 3.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect the formula to return? I You want to concatenate cells B&C, only if C is greater than 3? What's column E doing?

Comment: Don't believe there's a way to do this in a single cell - I tried to ask for a similar solution with luck in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112330/5090027

Comment: Hi user1342645. Did you abandon this question? There seems to be a good answer below. I assume you no longer need it for yourself, but at least accept the answer please. To do so, click the tick mark adjacent to the answer, so that it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1<3,A1,"")
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(B2<3,B2<>""),C1 & A2,C1)
```

and copy down.  Your answer will be the last value in column **C**:

[image]

Comment: Without VBA, I think this is the only solution - to use a helper column and combine each new row individually when it matches.