# How to concatenate range of cells in a row

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple Excel spreadsheet with a single row and 4 columns. I'm trying to concatenate 3 cells in the row together using a range instead of specifying all 3 cells explicitly (for times where I need to concatenate several cells).

The data is as follows:

```
[A1] 5
[B1] 6
[C1] 7
[D1] =CONCATENATE(A1:C1)
```

The result I get in D1 is #VALUE instead of what I'm looking for, which would be 567.

Is there a way to accomplish this using a range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365:

```
=CONCAT(A1:C1)
```

If not

```
=A1 & B1 & C1
```

or

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)
```

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016, not Office 365. Explicitly specifying the cells works, but it becomes a pain when there's 20 or 30 cells to concatenate.

Comment: Without Office 365, the only way with a formula is to do the individual cells, or a helper column.

Answer (score 0):

A helper column can gradually build the string, by concatenating above row with the next value.

```
  A  B      B (formula)
1 h  h      =A1        Initial value
2 e  he     =B1&A2     Concatenate above cell with next value
3 l  hel    =B2&A3     Copy formula downwards, it should auto-increment.
4 l  hell   =B3&A4
5 o  hello  =B4&A5
```

(Similar question: [Concatenate range in Excel with formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952513/concatenate-range-in-excel-with-formulas))