# I want an excel formula to do vlookup multiple times based on the Vlookup results it got for each Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have got a ton of bid-related information from the Government E-procurement site in India. I have columns like *Ministry*, *Organization*, *Department*, and *Office* which are in a hierarchical fashion like multiple offices inside *Department* with multiple departments inside an organization and organizations inside a ministry. I have a separate list of accounts that have salespeople aligned to it. Now my problem is to find a formula that will help me align the opportunities to each salesperson. I want the formula to go like this, first, it filters out all the results based on Ministry, then out of those filtered results, it filters out the *Organization/Department/Office* and returns the value from the list of accounts that have salespeople aligned to it. I also want it to skip if *Organization* is not present and move on to *Department*.

[Sample of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K5oTu_NsqTVX0w59BVpCx3qP1uPz_AD8/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105450635670039122002&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I tried using `VLOOKUP` after text-joining *Ministry*, *Organization*, *Department*, and *Office*, but it matches only the first word and hence the matches are not accurate.

I had a formula passed down to me but couldn't make any sense of it.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Organization Name]],ISR_alignment!$G$2:$H$22,2,FALSE),
    IFERROR(INDEX(ISR_alignment!$A$2:$A$72922,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(LOWER(
    ISR_alignment!$A$2:$A$72922),LOWER([@MDOOA]))),-1,1)*(ROW(
    ISR_alignment!$A$2:$A$72922))-ROW(ISR_alignment!$A$2)+1)),""))
```

Comment: Perhaps this or other similar posts may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31222926/4961700

Comment: use this.. it is much simpler..  --> https://exceljet.net/formulas/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Could you post an example of expected output?